# Sentence classification with tensorflow (Dynamic rnn)

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to implement a rnn model for sentence classification.
Precisely this is the schema I'm trying to implement

[image: Rnn schema]
Sentences are first encoded with word2vec vectors and then fed into the rnn, they can have different length hence I'm using a dynamic rnn.

Problem is that when running it seems the model is not learning at all.

Below you find my current implementation:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()

onehot_encoding_articles = tf.one_hot(int_article, len(set(articleIds)))

n_articles = len(set(articleIds))
seqLENGTH = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [RNN_batch_size])

inputX = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [RNN_batch_size, None])
inputs = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, inputX)
inputY = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [RNN_batch_size])
labels = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(onehot_encoding_articles, inputY)


rnn_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size) for size in [128, 256]]

multi_rnn_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(rnn_layers)

init_state = multi_rnn_cell.zero_state(RNN_batch_size, tf.float64)

outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=multi_rnn_cell,
                               inputs=inputs,
                               initial_state=init_state,
                               sequence_length=seqLENGTH,
                               dtype=tf.float64)

dense_layer = tf.layers.dense(state[1].h,32)

logits = tf.layers.dense(dense_layer,n_articles)

cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=labels,logits=logits)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)
```

Then I run it with

```
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess: 
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(1,5):
        batches = utils.get_batches_rnn(RNN_batch_size,int_wordsPerInteractionInput[:1000],int_article[:1000], len(embeddings)-1)
        for x, y, size in batches:
            feed = {inputX: x,
                inputY: y,
                seqLENGTH: size}
            train_loss, _ = sess.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict=feed)
            print("Avg. Training loss: {:.4f}".format(train_loss))
```

function get_batches_rnn is defined as follow

```
def get_batches_rnn(n_sentences_in_batch, sentences, articleIds, pad_index):  

    for idx in range(0, len(sentences), n_sentences_in_batch):
        x, y, batch_size = [], [], []
        x_batch = sentences[idx:idx+n_sentences_in_batch]
        y_batch = articleIds[idx:idx+n_sentences_in_batch]
        max_batch = max(len(x) for x in x_batch)
        for batchIndex in range(len(x_batch)):
        padding = [word for word in x_batch[batchIndex]]
           padSize = max_batch - len(x_batch[batchIndex])
           padding.extend(np.full((padSize), pad_index, dtype=int))
           x.append(padding)
           y.append(y_batch[batchIndex])
           batch_size.append(len(x_batch[batchIndex]))
        yield np.asarray(x), np.asarray(y), np.asarray(batch_size)
```

and this is an example of what is returned by the function

```
batches = utils.get_batches_rnn(3,int_wordsPerInteractionInput,int_article,len(embeddings)-1)
x, y, size = next(batches)
print(x)
print(y)
print(size)

Output:

[[   20     0 23342]
 [  122     8 23342]
 [  257   243    82]]
[452 468 521]
[2 2 3]
```

Basically the id of the word (that is then converted into word vector), the id of the class (that is then converted into one-hot encoded vector) and the length of the sentence.

I am padding with the id of the last word vector embedding (23342) because it is a zero vector.

Any hint about what I am doing wrong?